# Overloading streaming operators for a Boost Graph bundle output for GraphViz

Tags: c++, boost, graphviz, boost-graph, boost-property-map

Is it possible to use bundled properties in the Boost Graph Library, with a standard library type, while also using that type's overload of the `<<` stream operator to satisfy `write_graphviz`?

```
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>

namespace boost {
  namespace detail {
    namespace has_left_shift_impl {
      template <typename T>
      inline std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const std::array<T,2> &a) {
        o << a[0] << ',' << a[1];
        return o;
      }
    }
  }
}

static_assert(boost::has_left_shift<
                std::basic_ostream<char>,
                std::array<double,2>
              >::value,"");

int main()
{
  using namespace boost;
  typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, directedS, no_property, std::array<double,2>> Graph;
  Graph g;
  add_edge(0, 1, {123,456}, g);
  write_graphviz(std::cout, g, default_writer(),
                   make_label_writer(boost::get(edge_bundle,g)));
  return 0;
}
```

Faced with a Boost static assert, I modified my code to that above; adopting a suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569768/testing-for-the-presence-of-the-left-shift-operator), wherein the `<<` implementation is defined within the `boost::detail::has_left_shift_impl` namespace. Alas, I'm now faced with another error:

```
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:1624:50: error: cannot bind ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
                 bool const result = !(out_stream << input).fail();
```

Is there a way to provide an overload of `<<` which can be used by `write_graphviz`? I'm using Ubuntu 14.10 and GCC 4.9.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You couldn't even do

```
std::cout << g[add_edge(0,1,{123,456},g)];
```

without providing e.g.

```
inline static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::array<double, 2> const& doubles) {
    return os << "{" << doubles[0] << "," << doubles[1] << "}";
}
```

Now getting these overloads seen by `lexical_cast` at the right time is exceptionally hard to do portably (mostly because ADL won't help you with `std::array` and `double`).

***Instead*** you can use a value transforming property map (which is readonly of course):

```
std::string prettyprint(std::array<double, 2> const& arr) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "{" << arr[0] << "," << arr[1] << "}";
    return oss.str();
}
```

and then `make_transform_value_property_map(prettyprint, get(edge_bundle, g))`

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58556f78341a889e)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>

using namespace boost;

std::string prettyprint(std::array<double, 2> const& arr) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "{" << arr[0] << "," << arr[1] << "}";
    return oss.str();
}

int main()
{
    using namespace boost;
    typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, directedS, no_property, std::array<double,2>> Graph;
    Graph g;
    add_edge(0, 1, {123,456}, g);
    write_graphviz(std::cout, g, default_writer(),
            make_label_writer(make_transform_value_property_map(&prettyprint, get(edge_bundle, g))));
}
```

Prints

```
digraph G {
0;
1;
0->1 [label="{123,456}"];
}
```